# php WSDL (SOAP) client

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I have a problem co communicate with SOAP service in php:
My code for client:

```
$url = "https://XXXX.com/DataService.svc?singleWsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($url);
var_dump($client->__getFunctions()); // ExportScheduleData(ExportScheduleData $parameters)
$aclient->ExportScheduleData(array());
```

I got:

```
Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.
```

change soap version to 1.2:

```
$client = new SoapClient($url, array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
```

And request could not be completed: when I refresh page it still in loaging state - any errors or so.

===== update =====

Looks like service use WS-Security. They provide certificate file, but:

```
Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(): Unable to set local cert chain file `C:\xampp\htdocs\workspace\sandbox.dev\public\sandbox.cer'; Check that your cafile/capath settings include details of your certificate and its issuer in C:\xampp\htdocs\workspace\sandbox.dev\public\sandbox.php on line 34
```

Comment: According to the error message - your SOAP file isn't a SOAP file (at least not according to the document header); not a problem with the PHP as far as I can see at a quick glance.

Comment: Looks like you are right. Just for test my php installation and code I wrote some php code for other wsdl service. Both soap 1.1 and 1.2 are worked fine: WSDL functions worked also and I get correct responses. Maybe that service is have not valid wsdl. I will contact to their support.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
Write a Java application for ws-secutity check and and query java app from php script. I use java tcp server.